# Update sqlite cursor when table records changes?

Tags: android, database, cursor, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast Receiver that inserts info into a table when sms is received.
In the main activity i have a Cursor from a query on that table. Is it possible for me to set the cursor to requery every time the BR makes changes to the Table, so that it can reflect in the cursor.

I am currently not using OpenHelper, simply opening the database in the Activity and doing a query to obtain a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and probably easy.

- If you are using a Cursor, you should be using a CursorAdapter. Simply request a new Cursor and pass it to your adapter with `swapCursor()`.
- If you are using some other form of adapter, like an ArrayAdapter, call `add()` or `insert()`.

Either of these methods cause the View bound to your adapter to refresh automatically.

Comment: the main thing is i need the cursor to be updated every time the broadcast receiver detects an in coming sms message.I can detect the sms, but the cursor is present in a seperate activity , how can i update the cursor.

Comment: You can send an Intent to cause your Activity to call for a new Cursor or if you are certain the Activity is running you can use a global method. It's impossible to give you exact advice without seeing any code.

Comment: how can i do this , send an intent to get a new cursor i mean. As you said i cant be sure the activity is running.

Comment: An Intent will start the Activity if it is not running. Use `putExtra()` and `getBooleanExtra()` to store and retrieve a boolean in the Intent, if the boolean is present that means you should refresh your Cursor.

Comment: sorry for delayed reply, what i want is the cursor should update only if the Activity is running and currently being used by the user.Other wise i simply store the info in the database. i feel this is better as i am refreshing the cursor in the onResume() method.